# Why I'm unable to open/read txt file in C extension called from Python?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I try to pass file name from python to C\C++ .dll and make C\C++ code open/read that file.

Here is a very simple example of what I'm trying to achieve using ctypes. Please pardon noobness of my C++ code. I'm learning here.

```
//C++ code in example.cpp compiled to example.dll
#include <stdio.h>


extern "C" {

char* _line;
char* test(char* txt){
FILE* f_name;
f_name = fopen(txt, "r");

//... read data from file and do something 

_line = txt;
return _line; // this is just my sanity check to see if "file.txt" got passed from python
}
}
```

I use cygwin-64 to compile it to .dll:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared example.cpp -o example.dll
```

Python wrapper:

```
import ctypes

print("works!")  #just sanity check...

lib = ctypes.CDLL("example.dll")
cpp_file_access = lib.test
cpp_file_access.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
cpp_file_access.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

print(cpp_file_access(b"file.txt")) #sanity check to see if file name got passed
```

When test() in .dll is called from python, program doesn't gets past line:

```
f_name = fopen(txt, "r");
```

No matter which method I use to open/access  said txt file. It either "hangs" and does nothing or throws WindowsError indicating access violation 0x00000(...).
Thesame behaviour occurs when I use any kind of "print" function in C++ code like for example:

```
printf("test print !");
std::cout << "another test print";
```

The .dll code works in other cases properly unless I'm trying to open/read txt file or "print" something to the console in C++ code that is being called from python.
Actually, when I compile it to .exe file it opens/reads file and prints whatever to the console no problem.

I can't find any solution/answer to my problem.
Maybe someone here can enlighten me of what I'm doing wrong ?

[EDIT #1]
I noticed something.
When I tried to run this code in Python3.8, I got error message that files:

```
cygwin1.dll
cygstdc++-6.dll
cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
```

could not be located even if they are in bin folder of cygwin and env path is set correctly. I had to copy paste those files into the folder where example.dll and python wrapper (wrapper.py) were.
I don't know if that is of any relevance to my problem but I think it's worth mentioning. I'm starting to get very suspicious about that cygwin compiler. Digging continues.

[EDIT #2]
I modified C++ code by adding  void test_2() so there is no arguments passing between python and .dll.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void test_2(){
FILE* f_name;
f_name = fopen("file.txt", "r");
}
```

And call it from python:

```
void_acc = lib.test_2
void_acc.restype = None
void_acc()
print ("program ended, go away !") // .. sanity check
```

Issue remains thesame. Program execution is halted when it reaches fopen() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

It was compiler issue after all.
Instead of using cygwin I should've been using mingw-64 bit.

https://www.msys2.org/

I followed instructions in this yt video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXF4A5UeSeM

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two things at a glance:

- You have to make sure the function is exported using either __declspec(dllexport) before the function declaration or a by including it in a def file.  (If you're reaching the fopen line, this isn't the problem - just mentioning for completeness.)
- You've specified a wide c string pointer (c_wchar_t) in Python but declared narrow c strings (char*) in c, these will need to match.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for suggestions. As for the fopen() line. If I comment it out program executes properly - prints "file.txt" in python console. That's why I asked about opening/reading files cause this is clearly at fault in my case (or something else).

Comment: I still think the string could be the problem, since it's returning the pointer to the same string, it would appear unchanged so the return would be unaffected.  Try putting ```std::out << txt;```; before or in place of the ```fopen``` do you get "file.txt" or "f"?

Comment: I added 
inline `std::cout<<txt;`  It caused:
 `WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF`  
pointing to line in wrapper.py:
`print(cpp_file_access(b"file.txt"))`

Comment: Did you try with this change?

```cpp_file_access.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]``` and
```cpp_file_access.restype = ctypes.c_char_p```

Comment: Yes. I will edit the code. Now. TBH I didn't noticed any issues when it was ctypes.c_wchar_p but I changed it to be correct.

Comment: @Rad226 Two wrongs make a right. Pass a wchar* to a char* and pass back that char* as a wchar* without using it will appear to work, but fopen won’t like it.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Ok. However I added void to my C++ code (edit#2 above) where all I do is `fopen("file.txt", "r');` and it still doesn't work. Does "file.txt" as argument for fopen() , that is not being passed from python in this case, incorrect ? `std::cout<<"some text";` in void  also breaks.

Answer (score 1):

`.argtypes` and `.restype` are incorrect.  The C code uses `char*` so use `c_char_p`:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL("example.dll")
cpp_file_access = lib.test
cpp_file_access.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p,
cpp_file_access.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

print(cpp_file_access(b'file.txt')) # pass byte string
```

Note you don't need to wrap the parameter in a `ctypes` type.  `ctypes` knows the type from `.argtypes` already and will complain if you don't pass a Python type compatible with the declared type.

Comment: For python2 (not 3) it worked fine without complaints as long as fopen() line was commented out. Still thank you very much for this suggestion.

Comment: @Rad226 Make a [mcve].  This is the correct code to call a function with signature `char* test(char* txt)` for both Python 2 and 3 so the problem is in code you aren't showing.  What error do you get?

Comment: There is either no error and program execution "hangs" in console like it is waiting for input or when any type of "printing" from C++ code is performed like `sdt::cout<<"thing";` I get this error:     `WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF` . The other code I don't show is irrelevant. I pinpointed the source of problem to opening/reading file or printing to console from c++ code. Without those **everything** works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason yt link is down or you don't feel like watching video, I'll post steps from that viodeo for safekeeping.

Go to:
https://www.msys2.org/ and click on button that downloads the installer. In my case it was (this may vary in the future):

```
msys2-x86_64-20200602.exe
```

Install it. Remember where you installed it. This will come handy in few moments.
Once it's installed, launch it (or choose it launched automatically after installation is finished). Command line window will appear. In that command line window write/pasete:

```
pacman -Syu --disable-download-timeout
```

Wait for it to finish. Close the window afterwards.
Go to the installation folder you've choosen. Launch `msys2.exe`.Command line window will appear. Again write or paste:

```
pacman -Syu --disable-download-timeout
```

... and wait for it to finish. Leave the command line window open. We will be using it afterwards.
Once it's done, go to initial web page: https://www.msys2.org/ and scroll down, and go to "browse for: package list".
On the left go to "Search".
Set `"Search in"` filed to `"base packages"` and type `"gcc"` in searchbox. Choose:

```
mingw-w64-gcc
```

Then, from the `"binary packages"` list choose:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

Look for a `"Installation"` tag (it should be in top section of the page). There is a command there. Copy/paste it to terminal:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc --disable-download-timeout
```

(the `"--disable-download-timeout"` was added)
Wait for it to install. Leave the command line window open. 2 things to go.
In the command line window, re-paste the previous command but change last letters form `"gcc"` to `"gdb"` or use this:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb --disable-download-timeout
```

Wait for it to install. Leave the command line window open. 1 thing to go.
In the command line window, re-paste the previous command but change last letters form `"gdb"` to `"make"` or use this:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-make --disable-download-timeout
```

Wait for it to install. We are done with installing things. However there is one more step - system path variable.
Go to folder where you installed  `msys2-x86_64-20200602.exe`, there should be a `"msys2.exe"` file and a `"mingw64"` folder. Go to that folder. Look for `"bin"` folder, copy its path.
Go to system variables.
Right click on your computer icon. Go to Advanced system settings. Go to environmental variables (in the bottom section). Look for variable named "path", edit it. Put ";" at the end if it's not there allready. Paste the `<rest of the path>/mingw64/bin` folder path at the end after the ";".

Now you can use g++ command in terminal like:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared example.cpp -o example.dll
```

(for making a .dll file). You are done.